# Inline display method useful for quick inspection purposes

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Often, while investigating some code I'm developing, I'll throw in a `Console.WriteLine` here or there too see a value when the program is run. The drawback to `Console.WriteLine` is that I have to wrap an expression in parenthesis and possibly break it apart. For example given this expression:

```
a().b().c();
```

let's suppose I want to print the value of `b()`. I'll have to do something like:

```
var val = a().b();

Console.WriteLine(val);

val.c();
```

That's alot of editing just to see a value.

My solution has been to use this extension method:

```
public static T Disp<T>(this T obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

I can inject a call to `Disp` in any method chain without altering the value of the overall expression. To see the result of `b()` in the above example, I'd do:

```
a.().b().Disp().c()
```

My question is, is there already some method like `Disp` in .NET? Is there a better way to implement `Disp`? Are there drawbacks to this technique?

**update 2012-02-09**

I also added an overloaded version which accepts a format string:

```
public static T Disp<T>(this T obj, string format)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, obj));
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem with it, although you might consider making it more general with an `Action<T>` parameter:

```
public static T Tap<T>(this T obj, Action<T> act)
{
    act(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

This is similar to [Tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) in Ruby.

Instead of your `Dump` method you can then do:

```
a.().b().Tap(Console.WriteLine).c()
```

Comment: Good call. However, I'd probably still have a `Disp` defined in terms of `Tap` as a shorthand notation.

Answer (score 1):

LINQPad uses a `Dump` extension method in exactly this way.

The only downsides are common to all extension methods:

1. Extension methods are static, which restricts your flexibility in terms of overriding their behavior.
2. Any file that is "using" the extension method's namespace will see this method on every object. Intellisense gets cluttered and you run the risk of naming collisions.